# Why is searching for questions, that are not tagged as duplicate, giving duplicate questions results?

Tags: support, search

I want to answer some questions, so that I get some reputation, at least to do the most common actions in Stack Overflow. So, I wanted to search for questions without answers, in subjects I have good knowledge about. It was not hard to find out how specific tags can be searched. So I found one question to help, and answered it.

After that, I wanted more... but I noticed there were many results marked as "duplicate" (written `[duplicate]` in the subject). So, I read Search help again, to see how to search things excluding tags from the results. This is where it is failing for me.

To search a tag, we write it inside square brackets. For example, to search for threads about **[Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29)** scripts and uses, we may search for:

```
[bash]
```

And to exclude things from results (tags or words), we write a "-" sign attached before it. For example, we may search for:

```
-[duplicate]
```

One more important thing: have no answer. We just add `answers:0` to our query.

So, I decided to search for Bash-related questions that are not duplicates, and have not been answered yet. The query for that can be:

```
[bash] -[duplicate] answers:0
```

But the first two results are duplicates! Look:

[image: Screenshot of Stack Overflow site after searching for "[bash] -[duplicate] answers:0", showing the two first results are wrong, since they are duplicate questions.]

I tried to put the excluding term before the Bash tag, but the result is the same.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and leave only your actual question? There are so many non relevant details I can't edit myself. For example it's 100% not relevant that you posted after long time or got back to 1 rep, and many more details that got nothing to do with what you really ask.

Comment: @shadow: I tried editing out some irrelevant details. It should be focused now.

Comment: I did not like your editing, @Justin. They remove the context and how I got to the actual problem, and you also removed the parts where I said things I did. And this is part of something that makes the questions here have better chances to be answered, no being closed, and not being deleted.

Comment: No, you only need to get to the actual problem, in this case. The context is completely irrelevant here (as noted by another user).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`-[duplicate]` does not do what you think it is doing. That searches for questions that do not have the [duplicate](/questions/tagged/duplicate) tag on them. It has nothing to do with the question being *closed as a duplicate*. You were looking for `duplicate:no`.

Here's an example of a search with the query `[bash] duplicate:no answers:0`:

[image]

Note that this will give you Bash-related questions which do not have answers, and have not been marked as duplicates, **but**, this will also include questions which have been `[closed]` for other reasons (such questions will also be unanswerable).

So if you're looking for questions with no answers, and which have not been marked as [duplicate] or have not been [closed], then the proper search term would be `closed:no`:

[image]