# Can we format "How do I search?" similar to the "Markdown Editing Help"?

Tags: feature-request, design, help-center

There are a lot of excellent articles in the help center, albeit some being structured more convenient than others.

Take for example the [Markdown Editing Help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help). Each h2 level is a hyperlink to its own anchor, making it very easy to direct people to a specific part of the article. The article on [How do I search?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching) has no anchors, and as such can only be linked to in full. It would be helpful if we could easily redirect users to a specific part of this article, so can we get anchors here as well?

Example that could benefit from this:

- [This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/379110/why-is-searching-for-questions-that-are-not-tagged-as-duplicate-giving-duplica): OP fails to understand the difference between tags and boolean operators. A link to the Boolean operators section of the article would have directly shown how to use the `duplicate:0` argument.

Comment: This help center page is in need of other help too: [Markdown formatting problems in the Help Center article "How do I search?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/378966) | [Update Help Center's "How do I search?" with shorthand values for advanced search options](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193733)