# Clickable links on the editing help page redirect to the top of the help page

Tags: feature-request, editing-help, tables

There are two sections, "Alignment" and "Syntax details", under the "Tables" section on the [Markdown Editing Help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help) page.
It has the below clickable links:

- https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#alignment
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#syntax-details

But clicking on the links is redirecting to the top of the editing help page, instead of navigating to the exact section.

In my view, these two section titles ("Alignment" and "Syntax details") should be plain text, which matches the [Tables](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) section.

**Screenshots for reference:**

[image: Alignment]

---

[image: Syntax details]

Comment: Somewhat related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/380001/can-we-format-how-do-i-search-similar-to-the-markdown-editing-help If staff decided to fix this issue, would be nice if they could look into the linked post as well.

Answer (score 2):

You're right; this isn't working like the other sections. When you click a subheading of a different section, it shows up at the top of the page in a new, highlighted section:

[image: Highlighted "Links" section of Markdown help, displayed at the top of the Help Page]

It looks like the tables section just isn't rendering up there properly. I'm not sure whether this is something that broke, or whether it was never there to begin with, but either way, it would be nice if it could be fixed.

---

In addition, other sections of length or with multiple headings appear to be collapsible, which might be nice on the Table section as well:

[image: GIF showing that lengthy sections on the Markdown help page are collapsible]